# Different static blocks executed in java with an empty main and with an object initialization

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
class Developer{
    static{
        System.out.println("In static block Developer");
    }

    Developer(){
        System.out.println("In constructor Developer");
    }
}

public class Programmer extends Developer{
    static{
        System.out.println("In static block Programmer");
    }

    Programmer(){
        System.out.println("In constructor Programmer");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        //Different static block when no commented
        //Developer d = new Programmer(); 
    }
}
```

The output is this (when nothing in main):

> In static block Developer
>
> In static block Programmer

However, if I write in the main method Developer d = new Programmer() the ouput is:

> In static block Programmer
>
> In constructor Developer
>
> In constructor Programmer

The static block in class Developer is not executed. Is there any logical explanation?

Comment: Can't reproduce. When I execute the above code, with the main code uncommented, both static blocks are printed.

Comment: Can't reproduce. See http://ideone.com/WyDiKs

Comment: i'm getting all four Sysout statemnts

Comment: Is your compiled class in sync with the code you have posted?

Comment: In a plain text it prints the correct output, however in Eclipse without having another Developer class is wrong. I just try to check things with my Eclipse config

Comment: You may be referring to an old class w/o the `static` block. Try clean & rebuild

Comment: Thanks Reimeus. I think this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

The output

```
In static block Developer
```

should be generated since the `static` block will be executed when `Developer` is loaded by the class loader

Comment: He's asking why it _isn't_ executed.

Answer (score 0):

There are several rules in play

static blocks are always ran before the object is created, so that's why you see print message from both parents and childs static blocks
now, when you are calling constructor of the subclass (child), then this constructor implicitly calls super(); before executing it's own constructor. Initialization block comes into play even before the constructor call, so that's why is called first. So now your parent is created, program can continue creating child class which will undergo the same process.

Comment: Yes, I think I understand the order. My question is Why the static block in Developer is not executed when a Programmer object is created and Why it is executed when no objects are created.

Answer (score 0):

Static black always run no matter how you instantiation

I think if you execute `Developer d = new Programmer();`

output will be

```
In static block Developer
In static block Programmer
In constructor Developer
In constructor Programmer
```

Answer (score 0):

First the programmer class loads when you run its main but since it extends Developer so it loads Developer

so the static block of Developer gets executed Then the static block of Programmer gets executed now comes the turn of main() since you did `Developer d = new Programmer();` call goes to Programmer constructor where it finds super() implictly provided so call goes to Developer Constructor and prints its statement then the call comes to Programmers contructor again and prints its Statement

So output should be like

```
In static block Developer
In static block Programmer
In constructor Developer
In constructor Programmer
```

Comment: The thing is that "In static block Developer" is not printed.

Comment: but it is not being reproduced

Answer (score 0):

All the four prints will be displayed. Even if dont have the code in main , since we have written static  blocks for it. The class loader will load the class developer first and then the programmer. And as the base constructor is called first the output for the base constructor will be displayed first.